# Apache spark- bigdata

Tags: apache-spark, bigdata

Assume we have 100 gb of file. And my system is 60gb.How apache spark will handle this data?
We all know spark performs partitions on its own based on the cluster. But then when there is a reduced amount of memory I wanna know how spark handles it

Comment: 60GB of RAM? generally, Spark does not even persist data sets on disk unless you ask it to.

Comment: You mean persist data sets in memory? :)

Answer (score 5):

In short: Spark does not require the full dataset to fit in memory at once. However, some operations may demand an entire partition of the dataset to fit in memory. Note that Spark allows you to control the number of partitions (and, consequently, the size of them).

See [this](http://qnalist.com/questions/4940117/using-spark-on-data-size-larger-than-memory-size) topic for the details.

It is also worth to note that Java objects usually take more space than the raw data, so you may want to look at [this](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/tuning.html#memory-tuning).

Also i would recommend to look at [Apache Spark : Memory management and Graceful degradation](https://ogirardot.wordpress.com/2014/12/11/apache-spark-memory-management-and-graceful-degradation/)